# Can missing JS files be fixed?

Tags: support

I just tried browsing to the job preferences page (https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current) via the link on my profile:

[image]

This took an awfully long time (60 seconds) to load. I've taken a look at the network tab and it appears to be blocking on a couple of files:

**dropins.js** 
Served from `www.dropbox.com/static/api/2` which seems a very odd location to be serving JS from

**rules-p-c1rF4kxgLUzNcjs**
Served from `https://rules.quantcount.com/rules-p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc.js`

Both of these are failing with a connection closed error in Chrome `net:ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED`.

Comment: Can you add the link to your post? I don't see that block in my profile. (I probably disabled that somewhere in the settings, but I'm not going to look for it to turn it back on)

Comment: @Cerbrus sure - I've done that. In this case it was https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/21061

Comment: Nice. Quick update: you can replace the user Id with "current", in most SE Links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a problem on your end.

Either something in your browser, or your local network is blocking those scripts from loading. Both load just fine on my end.

Try disabling all extensions in your browser, first. If you have an adblocker or something similar, that might be a problem.

If you're behind a proxy or some firewall (Work / school network), your best bet would be to contact those responsible for the network you're on.

Comment: Thanks @Cerbrus, I wouldn't put it past our firewall to be honest.